# Importing default exports are undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

Im using TypeScript with Babel 7, Webpack 4 and React.

`export default () => <span>Test</span>`

And then

`import Test from './test'`

Test is at this point undefined or with `plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` an empty object.

.babelrc

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, ie 11, not dead"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "common",
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["declarations"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that `react-hot-loader` was responsible for the error, if I recall it correctly.